# CSS Sibling / Tilde as button "animation"

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is something like this possible?

```
<style>  
a,
a:active~a.active {
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
}
a.active,
a:active {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff; 
}
</style>
```

This CSS-Code is applied, but overwritten by a.active itself.
I tried !important, but that will overwrite a.active as well!

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/77eP4/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: `a:active~a.active` should never be overridden by `a.active`. Something else is wrong.

Comment: take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/77eP4/
If i click on "Link B", color and bgcolor of Link A should change while Link B is clicked (:active).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a:active~a.active` only applies to `a.active` elements that come *after* an `a:active` element. There is no selector to apply styles to `a.active` elements before `a:active`. You can't solve this with `!important` either; you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: you are right, it is applied only on elements coming after the clicked one. thanks! DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vfb9r/